# Problems and solutions book

Tags: math-mode, books

I am writing book with problems and solutions. And I am trying to find best way to get my pdf output like this

> Chapter One: Set of problems
>
> 1. Problem : blah bla ....
> 2. Problem : blah blah ....
> 3. Problem : blah blah .... ...
>
> Chapter Two: Solutions
>
> 1. Solution to problem 1
> 2. Solution to problem 2
> 3. Solution to problem 3 ...

But I want avoid manual referencing and want my code in following way

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Problem 1
\item Solution to problem 1
\item Problem 1
\item Solution to problem 1
\end{enumerate}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Have a look if some of these package could be helpful: https://www.ctan.org/topic/exam

Comment: I have found xsim https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim?lang=en to be quite good for this type of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Is this anything like you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\xsimsetup{collect}

\begin{document}

\section*{Set of problems}

\begin{exercise}[ID=A]
  $1+1=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  $2$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}[ID=B]
  $10\div2=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  5
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}[ID=C]
  Who has a red nosed reindeer?
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  santa
\end{solution}


\section*{Exercises}
\printrandomexercises[collection=all exercises,exclude=D]{3}

\newpage

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

You have to run the code twice for the exercises and solutions to appear on the separate pages.

Comment: What is paramtar exclude=D used for, also what is meaning of number {3}  in brackets after? Is it possible to make new section and print  different exerciese in it without repeating old exercises @Paul A

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a maths book? if so maybe the following would be more suitable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{number-only}{%
  \par\noindent
  \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
  \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
}{\par}

\newcommand\printsectionexercises{%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
    \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-   value}=\value{chapter}
    \noindent\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{instruction}\par
    \XSIMprint{exercise}{##1}{##2}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\renewcommand\printsolutions{%
  \def\currentchapter{}%
  \def\lastchapter{}%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
    \let\lastchapter\currentchapter
    \edef\currentchapter{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter- value}}%
    \ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else
    \section*{Chapter \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter}}
    \fi
    \XSIMprint{solution}{##1}{##2}%
  }%
}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{instruction}
\newcommand\ExerciseRef[1]{%
  \expanded{%
    \noexpand
    \ExercisePropertyGet{exercise}{\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{#1}}.   {counter-value}%
  }%
}
\newcommand\This{\GetExerciseProperty{counter-value}}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = number-only ,
  solution/template = number-only ,
  exercise/within = section ,
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
  exercise/print = false
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ChapterOne}
\section{Solving for an unknown}
\blindtext

\begin{exercise}[instruction={In Exercises \This--    \ExerciseRef{last:x}, solve for \(x\).}]
  \(x - 1 = 0\)
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \(x = 1\)
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
  \(3x - 12 = 0\)
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \(x = 4\)
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}[ID=last:x]
  \(x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0\)
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \(x = 1, 2\)
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[instruction={In Exercises \This--    \ExerciseRef{last:y}, solve for \(y\).}]
  \(y^3 - 6 y^2 + 11 y - 6 = 0\)
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \(y = 1, 2, 3\)
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[ID=last:y]
  \(y^4 - 10 y^3 + 35 y^2 - 50 y + 24 = 0\)
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \(y = 1, 2, 3, 4\)
\end{solution}

\subsection*{Exercises}
\printsectionexercises

\newpage

\chapter*{Solutions to the exercises}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

IS this the type of thing you want?

Comment: Dear Paul, I get error msg here.:                                                                                         Chapter 1.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   =
l.93 \printsectionexercises                                                                                                                     What should be changed/modified here?